# Why does remainder not work on Float values?

Tags: c

In C, why does remainder not work on a Float Values?

Comment: At a guess, because it wasn't a primitive operation in any early assembly language, so making it an operator would falsely imply speed matching other operators. On top of that, the use cases for it are really limited. The `fmod` and `remainder` functions exist, but the rules for handling negatives, special float values, etc., make it not worth direct (inflexible) operator support.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Comment good enough for an answer IMO, especially "the use cases for it are really limited."

Answer (score 0):

`remainder` takes a double (two, actually).  Use `remainderf`, not `remainder`.

Comment: remainder is a type generic macro bit I suspect OP means something else entirely.

Comment: C11 § 7.12.10.2 defines `remainder` as `double remainder(double x, double y);` in math.h.  It's only a type generic macro if you include tgmath.h, which most people avoid (IIRC MSVC still doesn't support tgmath.h).

Answer (score -1):

Because The `%` operator is only defined for integer type operands.